# Arduino turn on a led for 2 seconds and then turn off and wait 3 seconds and start all over again

Tags: algorithm, arduino, microcontroller

I'm using a microcontroler PIC 32 in a diligent  cerebot Mx4cK.
I have switch implemented on my protoboard and I want to turn on a led after the switch it's activated, then this led have to be in this state for 2 seconds and then have to be off for another 3 seconds and start all over again (on->2 seconds off->3 seconds)

This is my code so far, I think it's missing one condition but I can't find it... can you help me?

```
const int led=PIN_LED1;
const int pinSwitch1=16;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pinSwitch1,INPUT);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(led,LOW);
}
void loop()
{
   unsigned long actual_time=millis();
   static unsigned long cicle_time=0;
   static unsigned long off_time=0;
 
   static int switch_state1=0;

  switch_state1=digitalRead(pinSwitch1);

  if (switch_state1==HIGH)
  {
       if((actual_time-cicle_time)<5000)
     {
       digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
       cicle_time=actual_time; 
     }
       if((actual_time-off_time)>2000)
      {
       digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
      off_time=actual_time;
      }
                  
}
else 
{
  digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
}        

}
```

Actually my code, blincks for 2 seconds and it's not consider the 3 seconds that it has to be off.

[This is my new code, I missing an initial condition to light for the first time]

const int led=PIN_LED1;
const int pinSwitch1=16;

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(pinSwitch1,INPUT);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(led,LOW);
}
void loop()
{
   unsigned long actual_time=millis();
   static unsigned long cicle_time=0;
   static unsigned long off_time=0;
 
   static int switch_state1=0;
   
   static int cicle_on=0;

  switch_state1=digitalRead(pinSwitch1);

  if (switch_state1==HIGH)
  {
       if((actual_time-cicle_time)>5000)
     {
       digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
       cicle_time=actual_time; 
       cicle_on=HIGH;
     }
  }
 else 
{
  digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
}        

       if((actual_time-off_time)>2000)
      {
       digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
       off_time=actual_time;
       cicle_on=LOW;
      }
                  


}
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?. if not then what will millis(): return?

Comment: Millis ( ) it's a function if arduino :Returns the number of milliseconds since the Arduino board began running the current program. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days.

Comment: try out the solution which i have posted below..

Comment: I think this `if((actual_time-cicle_time)<5000)` is your main problem that if is always true while switch is on because inside you set `cicle_time=actual_time;` which gets it stuck to true forever. hence ignoring the 5sec period instead just LED off if is working blinking 2 or 4 sec period

Comment: I make a new code  and I think it will work, but I can't find the condition to light the led for the first time, so currently does not light at all.

Comment: @user_ing LOL (sorry for expression) you are obviously newbie to programing so program it as you should anyway. divide your task to smaller chunks ,code and test them independently/incrementaly and if they all works put them together. 1. program just blinking LED no switch, 2. add condition to blinking LED (hardcode it to true/false and test if it does what it have to) 3. fetch switch value to condition variable. Because when you do the whole thing at once you get lost and since on MCU is tracing the program difficult you have hard time debugging ...

Comment: I thought you realice I'm newbie programing MCU at the beginning of my question, I know it's basic but it's difficult to for me learn this, so I'm trying really hard! thank you for your advice I will try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. generic code debug is off-topic here

   - and you even do not specify what this does instead of what it should do
2. you are writing to LED every cycle

   - which slows things down
   - when you add more stuff then it could give you many head ages later
3. use absolute time instead of relative for your planned events and update only when needed

   ```
       static unsigned long time_LED_on =0xFFFFFFFF;
       static unsigned long time_LED_off=0xFFFFFFFF;
       //...
       if ((switch_state1==HIGH)&&(time_LED_on!=0xFFFFFFFF)) // init on switch toggle only would be better in interrupt
         {
         time_LED_on =actual_time;
         time_LED_off=actual_time+2000;
         }
       if (switch_state1==LOW ) // stop if switch off also would be better in interrupt
         {
         time_LED_on =0xFFFFFFFF;
         time_LED_off=0xFFFFFFFF;
         }
       // handle LED event
       if (time_LED_on >=actual_time) { digitalWrite(led,HIGH); time_LED_on +=5000; }
       if (time_LED_off>=actual_time) { digitalWrite(led,LOW ); time_LED_off+=5000; }
   ```

   - beware that time can overflow you can handle it by
   - `if (min(all_times) > max) all_times -= max;`
   - dont know how many bits your platform have if it is not 32 then change the `0xFFFFFFFF` acordingly

Comment: @user_ing btw some MCU's have PWM modules which can be configured to this task then you just start/stop it on switch interrupt and all the rest is done by HW. just set the ratio 2:3 and period to 5 seconds :)

Comment: It's a 32 bits platform, I will edit my question to clarify what my code do and not what should do, thank you

Comment: @user_ing you misunderstood leave that part what it should do as is. Just add what your code does instead what it should :) but your edit is exactly what I intended so never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
   const int led=PIN_LED1;
    const int pinSwitch1=16;
    unsigned long cicle_time=0;
    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(pinSwitch1,INPUT);
      pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }
    void loop()
    {
       unsigned long actual_time=0;
       static int switch_state1=0
       switch_state1=digitalRead(pinSwitch1);
       digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
         while(switch_state1==HIGH)
          {
            digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
            cicle_time=millis();
           while((millis()-cicle_time)!>=2000)
         {       
         }
         cicle_time=millis();
         digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
           while((millis()-circle_time)!>=3000)
          {  
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use delay, I need to use the relation of time that I expose in my question...

Comment: Are you sure millis() returns time in ms?

Comment: yes I do ! return just a number that represent the actual time of the program in ms